# MIPS twos complement conversion of 64 bit number with trailing 0's

Tags: mips, twos-complement, mips32

I am writing a 64 bit IEEE 754 adder/subtracter/multiplier

Currently working on the addition and subtraction part and the problem I have is that when my subtraction results in a negative number, the bits used by the number are in twos complement, but the rest of the bits in the registers are all 0's (when they should be 1's if it was properly twos complement)

I can't figure out how to convert a 64 bit number stored in 2 registers; say 
0x82b4effc 0x64000000, where the number itself (0x82b4effc64) is in twos complement followed by trailing zeros.

The only solution I have been able to think of is to completely reverse the number (since it could be anywhere from 1-64 bits), count the leading zeros, flip them, and reverse the number back, which would be a huge pain.

Comment: IEEE 754 doens't use two's complement. And to count the number of trailing zeros there were already tons of questions on SO. Do a search first

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I  know but for some reason my subtraction is has to return the number in twos complement when the result is negative or else I get an overflow error. I've been looking and can't find much related to doing it in mips I would appreciate it if you could point me in the right direction?